# Take contentd from url and place in container on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to find the last page name / directory from the url and display it on the page in a `<h3>` container. For example: /_blog/PunkLogic_News/tag/videos/ I would like to display 'videos' in a specific `<h3 class="urltag">` on the page. /_blog/PunkLogic_News/tag/Noosa_Biosphere/ I would like to display 'Noosa Biosphere' without the underscore. I suppose all special characters would need to be removed as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jackson

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var title = location.href.match(/([^\/]*)\/?$/)[1]; //get the last token
title = title.replace(/[^a-z\d\s]+/ig, ' '); //remove non-alphanumeric characters
$('h3.urltag').text(title); //set the title to h3
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubiwo3

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `window.location` object ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx)).

If you get the `window.location.pathname` parameter and perform some string manipulation (split, etc), you should be easily able to get the last 'part' of the url.

Have a look at the jQuery `.text()` method for inserting it into the `<h3>` element.